# Oracle AQ dequeuing an array

Tags: oracle, callback, queueing

Good day,
respective all!

Environment: Oracle 18XE 64-bit for Windows.

I have a question about dequeueing an array of messages from persistent queue.
It’s a simple point-to-point messaging. Queue is “single_consumer”, without propagation.

I registered my PL/SQL callback function.
I need to know  an exact size of array of messages to dequeue
in every call of my callback function from Oracle AQ internal job.

And I found the only legal way how to have done it. And this way is to register callback
with **qosflags** parameter of **sys.aq$reg_info**  equal to dbms_aq.NTFN_QOS_PAYLOAD.

Here is the registration PL/SQL block:

```
declare 
    v_qosflags number :=  dbms_aq.NTFN_QOS_PAYLOAD;
    r_info SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO;
   begin
      r_info := SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO(
                'STERN.FOUNDERS_QUEUE',
                DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ,
                'plsql://stern.dosomecalc',
                HEXTORAW('FF')
                );
       r_info.qosflags := v_qosflags; 
       r_info.ntfn_grouping_class := dbms_aq.NTFN_GROUPING_CLASS_TIME ;  
       r_info.ntfn_grouping_value := 60;
       r_info.ntfn_grouping_type := dbms_aq.NTFN_GROUPING_TYPE_SUMMARY ;    
       
       DBMS_AQ.REGISTER (
          SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO_LIST(
                     r_info
             ),
          1
          );
 end;
```

Here is the declaration of callback procedure. It is a standard declaration:

```
create or replace procedure dosomecalc
(context    RAW
                             ,reginfo    SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO
                             ,descr      SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR
                             ,payload    raw
                             ,payloadl   NUMBER)
```

Now, thankfully to **qosflags** parameter initialized with dbms_aq.NTFN_QOS_PAYLOAD  ,my callback function is registered in such a way that I always can see  real size
of messages to dequeue in callback session.
This size is evaluated as counting size of **descr.msgid_array** part of **descr** parameter.
Without setting of **qosflags** during registration to some value - this part of **descr** parameter  always comes empty to callback procedure call.

Once I know the real size of messages array , I can use it in

```
Dbms_aq.dequeue_array(…, array_size => descr.msgid_array.count,…)
```

dequeuing call inside my callback function.

Than, after investigating contents of  descr parameter, I found in it an **ntfnsRecdInGrp** element,
and decided that  **ntfnsRecdInGrp** is always equal to **descr.msgid_array.count**,
and  just made for programmer’s convenience, just for duplicate  **descr.msgid_array.count**.

AQ documentation says:

```
msgid_array  - Group notification message ID list 
ntfnsRecdInGrp - Notifications received in group
```

That was why I decided that they are equal by value.
It was a my mistake. When I use callback with array size equal to **descr.msgid_array.count** –
everything is OK. With **ntfnsRecdInGrp** – no. Sometimes **descr.msgid_array.count**
and **ntfnsRecdInGrp**  equal to each other, sometimes not.

Now the question is:

What is the meaning of **ntfnsRecdInGrp** part of descr parameter?

Why it is not the same as **msgid_array.count**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I have a question about AQ$_<queue_table_name>_F. It is not docummented. Does anybody know what is this? It exists in Oracle 18c.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no real feedback between PLSQL_NTFN job and what things callback function had already did

Comment: Here the answer on this question that I posted on asktom:https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=advanced-queueing-202101